# How to Create Timeline UI on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, rss, feed, timeline

I want to create android application that read RSS feed from some websites. My application should be like this picture below. I don't know how to create timeline UI like this. Should i use webView to create IU like this, or there's any other approach ?

[image: Timeline UI]

Comment: Do you mean a `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Card UI, this could get your job done.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no significance of using a webView for a timeline layout. You would (almost) definitely be using a [listView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) or (even better) [recyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/.../RecyclerView.html).
Additionally, to comply with new material design guidelines, you can use `cardView`. see [Creating lists and cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).
These are basic design elements. You should at least be familiar with listView implementations if you intend to create such a UI. Here is a nice tutorial about using a `listView`.

[Vogella - Using lists in Android](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)